# How to change from a view in navigationcontroller to a view in a tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In the storyboard I have set up a tabbar controller where the first tab leads to a navigation controller with several view controllers while the second tab leads to a view controller.

When I press a button in the navigation controller I want to make a switch to the second tab view controller. It doesn't work if I perform a modal segue because then the tabbar is hidden and neither if I use a push segue because then the second view shows up as the first tab.

I hope you get my question and appreciate every answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the button method just call the setSelectedIndex: method of the tab bar controller:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```